# passing objects to another activity

Tags: android, android-activity

**Situation**

In my alarm clock app I start a `NewAlarmActivity` by clicking a button.
After the user has made all the selections, alarm gets set and `finish() is called.

**The matter**

I create a new `LinearLayout` object with images and text within it. That layout must be added to the screen of previous activity (to another `LinearLayout` placed inside a `ScrollView`) so the user is able to see the alarm set. Somehow I have to pass that `LinearLayout` object to the first activity and tell it to receive and add the object to the screen.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to read some documentation about `startActivityForResult()`.

BTW, IMHO, you should not transport your `LinearLayout` object between activities, that's ugly.

[How to manage `startActivityForResult` on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407159/android-how-to-manage-start-activity-for-result)

[Starting Activity And Getting Result](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#StartingActivities)

*This has been asked countless times...*

Comment: just one question: the putExtra() method won't accept a LinearLayout object as parameter. How to solve that?

Comment: You should not transport the `LinearLayout` but data that will allow the second view to build that `LinearLayout` itself.

Answer (score 1):

No You don't have to do this. Try the approach of storing your data into a database and then when going into that Activity, build your layout according to the data you have. This is a much better way than passing a layout from one Activity to antoher.

Comment: any tutorials or examples please..? never did it before

Comment: Just look up databases and creating views dynamically and you should be good.

Comment: No need to go through a database unless you want this setting to be persisted. Just use a singleton do it all in memory.

Comment: I dont know if using memory is the best option @dnkoutso ... According to the sound of his Activity, it sounds like a Settings Activity, which ideally is persisting this data somewhere, might as well use the persisted data instead of using memory imho.

Comment: You are right, I use a PreferenceActivity to set up an alarm. The thing is when the user is done, a broadcast is sent to the corresponding Receiver and (how I planned it) a new LinearLayout ist created according to user's infromation. Now the same activity must be ready to use to set up an another alarm

Comment: Build your new View according to the data in the database, best way to do it.